# c# code executing in the wrong order - weird behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, events, windows-runtime

I have a `ListView` bound to a view model which contains an `ObservableCollection` in a simple example app.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel(){}

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Item> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items 
    {
        get 
        { 
            return this._items; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._items)
            {
                this._items = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Items"));
            }
        }         
    }
}
public class Item
{
    public string Name;
}
```

The following function is bound to the SelectionChanged event of the ListView

```
private void ItemListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    model.Items.Add(new Item { Name = "added item" });
    model.Items = new ObservableCollection<Item> { new Item { Name = "new item 1" }};
}
```

When the event fires, this should happen

1. new item ("added item") appended to existing `ObservableCollection`
2. `ObservableCollection` set to a new collection [single item, "new item 1"]

What actually happens:

1. `ObservableCollection` set to new collection [single item, "new item 1"]
2. new item ("added item") appended to end of *new* collection

Can anyone explain why these are happening in the wrong order?

Comment: If you use ObservableCollection, why do you create new instance of the collection each time? Can't you just operate on existing one?

Comment: _items should be private and new it.  And if you want to want a fresh collection clear it don't new it.   And changing the collection in SelectionChanged is slippery ground.  +1 Henk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone explain why these are happening in the wrong order?

My guess is that they're not happening in the wrong (reversed) order but the append is happening twice. Executing

```
 model.Items = ... ;
```

in the SelectionChanged of those same Items is pretty bold. It will trigger a SelectionChanged again, and only because the Selection then remains at none (Index -1) you do not get into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

observable collection not need inotify, try this:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel(){}



    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items ;

}
```

Comment: Should be: public ObservableCollection<Item> Items {get; private set;} and initialize it at constructor.